# Is it possible to schedule the printer to print page by page

Tags: c#, printdocument

I have an A3-sized print document that contains images customer provide and it will fill up the document through calculation (There could sometimes be more than 300 images at once being computed to printDocument). The problem I am facing now is that when it is sent to the printer the document is too big for the printer memory to handle. Is there a way to let printer to print page as soon as it is sent rather than the whole document? My colleague suggest to break those pages to a different document. Is that possible?

I have scour through the documentation and there seems to be no way for the printDocument or printerController to talk with the printer to start printing page as soon as it receives.

On my test run I have a job of 360 images stuffed into 28 pages and the document spool data went up to 2.71GB
[Screenshot of the print queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTwof.png)

```
private void PrintPageEventHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    //set some settings
    //loop until the page has been filled up by images
    while(counter < maxImageAllowedPerPage)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, currentPoint.X + posX, currentPoint.Y + 
             posY, newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    e.Graphics.Dispose();
    e.HasMorePages = (PrintedImageCount != TotalImageCount);
}
```

Comment: You are exceeding the print buffer size.  You may be able to bypass the buffer by writing directly to the  printer IP address.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with your colleague, it doesn't seem like it is one document of many pages anyway, its many pages, so create a new document every time the 'page' is full make a lot of sense (plus you could then save these for later printing).  You're creating a document now, but add some of your print code if that's the area you need further assistance in.

Comment: @jdweng how you address the printer wont change things, the printer will still have to buffer the entire document as it has to translate it into its native commands/logic.

Comment: Because I've done it lots of times before.  What you do is add a new printer but instead of selecting the PC name that is used as the print server use the option to in printer setup to use an IP address of the printer.

Comment: @cjb110 I've added how I generate the document during PrntPageEventHandler not sure if that's enough

Comment: @jdweng The printer does have an IP address but I am not sure how does that work can u clarify it more? Meaning I am sending the document to that IP instead of the printerName available?

Comment: Normally companies setup a Print Server to be used as a spooler so more than one person can use printer.  The spooler has has a maximum memory size.  Writing directly to the printer bypasses the spooler.  The print data will go directly to the printer and when the printer will only request more printer data when it has the memory available to support more data.  It really depends on the software in the printer and the driver in your PC if it will work.  Printer Vendors usually design software to handle very large files when sent directly to the printer.

Comment: What's the problem with breaking it up into individual documents? Just end the print job after each page. You are already ending the print job after all pages are written - just do it earlier.

Comment: Unrelated (event though related :), don't do this: `e.Graphics.Dispose();`, you cannot dispose of that object.

Comment: @KubaOber I don't know if breaking it up to multiple documents is a viable approach to break it into multiple documents, also I am not sure if it is the document spool issue that causes it as I am not that familiar with how the print queue in Windows works. The last thing in my mind is can I do some settings that will allow such operation without much alteration to my code

Comment: @Jimi Initially I was debugging where the memory explodes when there are too many images so I added this for safety precaution, thanks for the headsup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with something similar to @cjb110's answer

```
//initialize the print docuemnts with all settings required
var printDocument = new PrintDocument();
printDocument.PrintedImageCount = 0;
printDocument.TotalImageCount = 150;

while(printDocument.PrintedImageCount != printDocument.TotalImageCount){
    printDocument.Print();
}
```

As of current the printer is able to handle based on my test print 30 document being sent to the printer without crashing, and my client will monitor on their own to see how many document can the printer accept until it crash to see if I need to implement a limitation to prevent too many docuemnt being sent at once.

Thanks to all that have suggest different kind of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.8) for PrintDocument, you should just need to move your loop.

So something like

```
while(counter < maxImageAllowedPerPage)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintPageEventHandler);
    pd.Print();
}
```

Not sure how your determining which `image`'s to print, but you'll need to do that in this loop too, probably before the final `Print()`, as that is what will fire the Event Handler. Possibly you'll want two collections of 'images', your complete collection of images, and a collection that is filled for each page, so you'll fill that second collection in the loop above and the PrintPage EV will read from that collection.

Oh and HasMorePages will always be false now.

Comment: Hi thanks for your solution yup i reworked my code to look something similar to that haha, the only thing I am worried now is that the print queue overflow, but I can always add a Thread.sleep() to ensure the previous print job has finished. THansk for your solution :D